# Generating dynamic pdf using itext

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, itext

I need to generate pdf dynamically where there could be different number of components and different number of lines in accordance with user needs, I made use of itext where i made use of page break statically.

Can i do it without defining page break and it could just happen in accordance with the height of components and the height of a4 size sheet in itext or a client side library which can serve my purpose in better way.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I was able to use page break statically." What do you mean when you say "Can I use page break dynamically?" You can generate PDFs dynamically and you can control page breaks. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Also: pdf.js is an HTML 5 / JavaScript based PDF client-side *viewer*. It doesn't create PDFs. iText is a server-side Java / C# library to create PDFs (it is *not a viewer*). I don't understand why you'd compare a PDF creation/manipulation library with a PDF viewer library. I voted to close your question as it is *unclear what you're asking.*

Comment: Sorry for being so unclear, i have edited my question, hope to get a better reply.

Comment: @Neha if you use the normal iText high level API, you simply add content to the document and iText automatically starts a new page whenever the space on the former page is filled up. Thus, you seem to use iText in a different, special way. If you want help, you should, therefore, show your way.

Comment: @NehaAcharya As mkl explains, the question is still unclear.